# Não estou conseguindo chamar o JOptionPane no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Galera, não estou conseguindo chamar o `JOptionPane` em nenhuma classe no eclipse, tentei no Netbeans, e rodou normal. Alguém ai pode saber o que pode ser?

Mensagem de erro:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Access restriction: The type JOptionPane is not accessible due to restriction on required library C: \Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\rt.jar
>   - Access restriction: The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) from the type JOptionPane  is not accessible due to restriction on
>   required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\rt.jar

Código:

```
package br.projeto.model;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Caixa {

Cliente client = new Cliente();

public void showAvaibleBalance(Cliente client){
    client.getBalance();
}

public void makeLoot(Cliente client, double value){
    if((value > 0)&&(value < client.getBalance())){
        client.setBalance(client.getBalance()-value);
    }else if (value < 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Cara, resolveu ! Muito obrigado !! Já tava ficando louco kkkk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute os seguintes procedimentos para solucionar este problema:

1. Menu "Window" -> "Preferences"
2. Na janela que abrir, expanda "Java" -> "Compiler" e escolha
   "Errors/Warnings"
3. Do lado direito expanda "Deprecated and restricted API" e em
   "Forbidden reference (acess rules)" escolha "Ignore"
4. Clique em "OK"
5. O Eclipse irá pedir a confirmação. Escolha "Yes" e espere ele
   recompilar as classes.

Fonte: http://respostas.guj.com.br/33156-erro-joptionpane